# How to move listeners of an ExpandableListAdapater to the calling activity

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have tried to search for this particular issue online to no avail. I have a fragment (one tab of the main activity) that contains 3 different Expandable Lists. As such, I have 3 ExpandableListAdapter classes, each with their own widget listeners. I want to be able to use just one ExpandableListAdapter class in a generic way instead of having 3 with mostly similar code.

The main roadblock I see is how to move the distinct listeners within each ExpandableListAdapter to a separate class so that the ExpandableListAdapter can be more generic. I am wondering if this is even possible due to the way the list is expanded. How do I get the widget's ID for each child since I cannot designate the IDs in the child_list.xml.

(I can post code if desired but I thought this question was general enough to understand.)

Thanks!